# Is it possible to remove speakers from Camry and put it in a Versa?

Tags: toyota, nissan, audio

So I have a 2007 Toyota Camry with a blown head gasket. I found a company to buy the car and their requirements of what needs to be functional is pretty basic. So I am sure I can take my speakers off of the Camry before I let them take the car.

I bought a 2015 Nissan Versa a few days back and the stereo system in that one is bad. Like, really bad. I thought maybe my volume is low, but volume turned up makes it sound like a megaphone. No clarity, jarring, and just painful.

So these are my questions:

1. Is it possible to just remove the speakers from my Camry and attach it to my Versa?
2. Is it possible to attach both my Camry speakers AND my Versa speakers to my Versa?
3. Is it possible to just completely move the stereo system, the console and everything, from my Camry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the 2007 Toyota Camry featured 6" x 9" oval speakers in both the front and rear.  These are quite large, oval shaped speakers (and in my experience, give a loud and full bodied sound).  The speakers in your 2015 Nissan Versa are 6.5" round in both the front and rear.

What this effectively means is that the speakers from the Toyota won't fit in the spaces the speakers in the Nissan go.  This does not mean that you can't still use them however.  You have the option of enlarging the existing spaces in the Nissan or you could mount the Toyota speakers in a different location.  The load bay shelf is a favourite location for 6x9 speakers.

The stereo in your Nissan will have four amplified speaker outputs (left and right, front and rear).  If you wish to replace the standard speakers with larger ones, you can swap them over.  If you wish to have all speakers working at the same time (i.e. 8 speakers) you may be better purchasing a small, car amplifier with an additional four speaker outputs.

Personally, the first setup I would try would be to install a pair of the 6x9 speakers in the rear of the Nissan.  Either in the original location or on the parcel shelf.  Then run these rear speakers with the two rear channels from the stereo.  This ought to give a quite considerable upgrade to the sound within the car for a minimal amount of hassle.  Of course you can go all out and install a full eight speaker system but I'd try 6.5" up front and 6x9 in the rear first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to move audio system from one car to another. However it might need some work if the speakers are different size. Even then it's not big deal moving the speakers.